# Kotlin Result when awaited fails with exception while running in "runBlocking"

Tags: kotlin

Please see the code below, the main function with suspend modifier works fine, but when ran with run blocking the await behaves prematurely and the Result is returned with the coroutine object instead of actual value.

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.async
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking

typealias SuspendingResultFunction<T, A> = suspend (T) -> Result<A>

suspend fun <T, R> Result<T>.then(transform: SuspendingResultFunction<T, R>): Result<R> {
    return if (this.isSuccess) transform(this.getOrNull()!!)
    else Result.failure(this.exceptionOrNull()!!)
}

private suspend fun suspendingFunction(no: Int): Result<Int> {
    val plusOneTask = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).async { delayedPlusOne(no) }
    val plusOne = plusOneTask.await()
    return Result.success(plusOne)
}

private suspend fun delayedPlusOne(no: Int): Int {
    delay(1000L)
    return no + 1
}

suspend fun main_with_suspend_works_good() {
    val threeResult = suspendingFunction(1).then { suspendingFunction(it) }
    val three = threeResult.getOrNull()
    println(three)
}

fun main() {
    runBlocking {
        val threeResult = suspendingFunction(1).then { suspendingFunction(it) }
        val three = threeResult.getOrNull()
        println(three)
        // above line throws the exception, once the execution reach to await.
        // : class kotlin.coroutines.intrinsics.CoroutineSingletons cannot be cast to class java.lang.Number (kotlin.coroutines.intrinsics
    }
    // When we use junit for testing we suppose to use runBlocking !!
    // But even why runBlocking does not work ?
}
```

Comment: It might be unrelated, but what's the point of your `CoroutineScope()` here? It doesn't look right to create a scope like this for this purpose. If you just want to switch dispatchers at this point, you should use `withContext(Dispatchers.Defautl)` instead, and you won't need to `await`.

Comment: Right, withContext works good for this specific example. But the actual code uses await differently. I have 3 tasks that are IO and I need to run them parallel and await all. For the same the I have created a custom map like this, which requires await.

Please see mapPar in here https://gist.github.com/abdulkaderjeelani/8814f8476ea277ccb6fe2e88a70e1666

Comment: For my actual use case if I try to use withContext (see gist below) the behavior changes sequentially. For each item in the map the call is suspended and resumed and then suspended for next and so on. https://gist.github.com/abdulkaderjeelani/ef3a4fd727e602774e85c3f2c5d27d08

Comment: It looks you're trying to rewrite some pieces of coroutine library here. Why do you need all this? Usually if you need multiple `async` in parallel you can wrap all in a `coroutineScope { ... }` (which suspends) and call multiple `async {}`, then multiple `await`. It would help to see the higher level structure of code, but I would bet it can be simplified further.

Comment: Joffery, If you look at the mapPar implementation, That is the intention to start multiple async and then await all. In a nutshell, I need a parallel map, because the N is not known it could be 3,4,10 or even 50. Idea is that, for each element in the collection start an async task which will kick them concurrently and then await all

Answer (score 0):

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-46574
Kotlin team has resolved the issue, Hope it would be available soon in public.

Answer (score -1):

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.async
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking

typealias SuspendingResultFunction<T, A> = suspend (T) -> Result<A>

suspend fun <T, R> Result<T>.then(transform: SuspendingResultFunction<T, R>): Result<R> {
    return if (this.isSuccess) transform(this.getOrNull()!!)
    else Result.failure(this.exceptionOrNull()!!)
}

private suspend fun suspendingFunction(no: Int): Result<Int> {
    val plusOneTask = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).async { delayedPlusOne(no) }
    val plusOne = plusOneTask.await()
    return Result.success(plusOne)
}

private suspend fun delayedPlusOne(no: Int): Int {
    delay(1000L)
    return no + 1
}

suspend fun main_works_good() {
    val threeResult = suspendingFunction(1).then { suspendingFunction(it) }
    val three = threeResult.getOrNull()
    println(three)
}

fun main() {
    runBlocking {
        val threeResult = suspendingFunction(1).then { suspendingFunction(it) }
        val three = threeResult.getOrNull()
        println(three)
        // above line throws the exception, once the execution reach to await.
        // : class kotlin.coroutines.intrinsics.CoroutineSingletons cannot be cast to class java.lang.Number (kotlin.coroutines.intrinsics
    }
    // When we use junit for testing we suppose to use runBlocking !!
    // But even why runBlocking does not work ?
}

sealed class Result<out A> {

    companion object {
        fun <T> success(t: T) = Success(t)
        fun failure(ex: Throwable) = Failure(ex)
    }

   
    inline fun <T> match(onSuccess: (A) -> T, onFailure: (Throwable) -> T): T =
    when (this) {
        is Success<A> -> onSuccess(this.data)
        is Failure -> onFailure(this.ex)
    }

    inline fun <T> map(onSuccess: (A) -> T): Response<T> = match({ 
    success(onSuccess(it)) }, { failure(it) })

    inline fun <T> flatMap(onSuccess: (A) -> Response<T>): Response<T> 
    = match(onSuccess) { failure(it) }

    fun getOrNull(): A? = this.match({ it }, { null })

    fun exceptionOrNull(): Throwable? = this.match({ null }, { it })

    private fun isGood() = this is Success<*>

    val isSuccess = isGood()

    val isFailure = !isGood()
}

// this needs to be outside of the result class because this uses input variance !
inline fun <T> Result<T>.getOrElse(orElse: (Throwable) -> T): T = this.match({ it }, orElse)

data class Success<A>(val data: A) : Result<A>()
data class Failure(val ex: Throwable) : Result<Nothing>()
```

`

I suspected Kotlin.Result type, so tried to implement by own Result Type, it works good.

Update: Perhaps this is an issue with all inline classes not limited to Kotlin Result, It is better to respect Kotlin compiler warning and not use Result as return types.

Related issue in here - youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-30223

Comment: Why don't you just use the `Deferred`?

Comment: The above issue link took me here, which has some good details https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-30223

Comment: Perhaps, the problem with the behaviour of Inline classes. For my case a custom sealed class does the Job. While it is not the actual "answer" / "solution" for the problem. It works quite well to satisfy the needs. Until this is addressed in Kotlin, I see this as a good interim solution.

Comment: I need the result of deferred. In a nutshell, I need an parallel map. Idea is to for element in the collection start an async task which will kick them concurrently and then await all. e.g. what I am looking for is List<Int> vs List<Deferred<Int>> 

The API is expected to return the result of the deferred as in, Result<List<Int>>